# Extra padding/blank space on top of the screen when using Drawer layout from expo-router (React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo, padding, react-native-flatlist, expo-router

I'm working on a story reading React Native mobile app with expo-router. I put everything in a Drawer layout from expo-router.

I noticed that there is an extra white space above the header. When I inspect the header, it covers the white space but shows 0 padding and margins.

The white space is gone when I use the desktop web instead of android app.

[White space above header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DlTi.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.